# getBoundingClientRect() returns undefined on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, reactjs, web, frontend

I am trying to implement Drag N Drop feature in my ReactFlow graph but am facing the following issue.

I am using this example -"https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/interaction/drag-and-drop/"

Was trying to implement this in my ReactFlow component but it returns undefined when I try to use it through the onLoad prop to instantiate the useRef variable while using that in the onDrop callback to get the accurate position of the cursor on the DOM so that the drag and drop of the component happens correctly.

Code-

```
  const reactFlowWrapper = useRef(null);

 const onDrop = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const reactFlowBounds = reactFlowWrapper.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
      const type = event.dataTransfer.getData("application/reactflow");

      if (!type || !reactFlowBounds) {
        return;
      }
      const position = reactFlowInstance.project({
        x: event.clientX - reactFlowBounds.left,
        y: event.clientY - reactFlowBounds.top,
      });

      const newNode = {
        id: getId(),
        type,
        position,
        data: { label: `${type} ${this.id}` },
      };
      setNodes((nds) => nds.concat(newNode));
    },
    [reactFlowInstance]
  );

return (
        <ReactFlow
          onEdgeClick={(e, edge) => handleEdgeClick(e, edge)}
          onLoad={(_reactFlowInstance) => {
            reactFlowWrapper.current = _reactFlowInstance;
          }}
          nodes={nodes}
          edges={edges}
          onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
          onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
          nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
          edgeTypes={edgeTypes}
          onConnect={onConnect}
          connectionMode="strict"
          connectionLineType={ConnectionLineType.SimpleBezier}
          proOptions={{ hideAttribution: true }}
          defaultZoom={0.8}
          minZoom={0.3}
          maxZoom={3}
          onNodeDragStart={handleNodeDragStart}
          onNodeDragStop={handleNodeDragStop}
          onInit={setReactFlowInstance}
          onDrop={onDrop}
          onDragOver={onDragOver}
          fitView
        >
          <div ref={boxRef} className="MuiBox-root">
            <Controls />
            <Background />
          </div>
        </ReactFlow>
)
```

While console logging the onDrop function variables It only prints reactFlowBounds and type with response as undefined and the correct type of node selected as rest of the onDrop code doesn't execute as the reactFlowBounds isn't getting any value from the getBoundingClientRect() func.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` itself can not return undefined. You are getting undefined here, because `reactFlowWrapper.current` apparently is not set.